# passing Initialized object from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity and a fragment and I want to pass an object which is initialized and it belongs to Network class and here is the object  initialization

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

when I directly put this line in fragment it shows error on getBaseContext and getSystemService so how should I call this object from activity to fragment

Comment: your question is unclear. Please add more code and explain exactly what you want. Do you want to initialize this object in Activity and then pass it onto Fragment? Or do you want to Initialize in Fragment?

Comment: your both options are great its good to go with your first option and more better with the second one option

Comment: hey i want this object on my fragment ,its going good when i write this code in my activity but if i write in my fragment then error occurs by saying cannot resolve the method

Answer (score 0):

I would advise just initialize it in the Fragment, no need to pass it from the Activity. The only way you can pass such an Item from the Activity is if it can be Serialized or is `Parcelable` e.g. `ConnectivityManager` implements `Serializable` or `Parcelable` respectively. Since you did not create these classes and they are part of the AndroidFramework, I would not assume they are, unless you can verify that by checking the sourcecode.

Nonetheless, to initialize it in a Fragment, call the following code

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getContext()
             .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSystemService()` is a method in the `Context` class. `Fragment` does **not** inherit from `Context` and thus the method isn't available. You need to call the method on a reference to the `Activity` (which inherits from `Context`) like this:

```
(ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a fragment. So you have to use the Context of it's parent activity. 
Do it this way in your fragment instead:

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `Context` to your `Fragment`. Make the `Fragment` constructor like so:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
Context context;
public MyFragment(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}
```

and Initialize your `Fragment` in `Activity` Like so:

```
MyFragment mFrag = new MyFragment(this);
```

Then use this context while initializing `ConnectivityManager` and anywhere else